# AngularJS : How can I dynamically reference a directive during ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

**[Here is a plunkr showing what I am attempting](http://plnkr.co/edit/yHfmdktnbUKHgBj4naOT?p=preview)**

I have a tabset, which is defined as individual tabs, each with their own directive.

```
<div class="container" ng-controller='fruitController'>
        <tabset type="pills" class="tabs-left">
            <tab heading="Apple" class="hand_pointer">
                <br/>
                <div data-fruit-apple></div>
            </tab>

            <tab heading="Banana"class="hand_pointer">
                <br/>
                <div  data-fruit-banana></div>
            </tab>

            <tab heading="Cherry"class="hand_pointer">
                <br/>
                <div  data-fruit-cherry></div>
            </tab>
        </tabset>
</div>
```

Each of these directives can access objects created in the `$scope` of the `fruitController`.

I would like to be able to use ng-repeat to define many tabs and have naively done the following:

**Controller**

```
        $scope.tabs = [
                   { title:"Apple", directive: "data-fruit-apple" },
                   { title:"Banana", directive: "data-fruit-banana" },
                   { title:"Cherry", directive: "data-fruit-cherry" }
        ];
```

**Template**

```
        <tabset type="pills" class="tabs-left">
            <tab heading="{{tab.title}}" class="hand_pointer" active="tab.active" ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
                <br/>
                <div id="content" data-fruit-apple></div>
            </tab>
        </tabset>
```

Obviously this will give each tab the incorrect (Apple) directive, how would I go about making Angular use the directive I defined in the controller?

My directives are defined like:

```
app.directive('fruitApple', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/fruit/appleTemplate.html'
    }
}
```

**I have tried:**

```
<div id="content" class="{{tab.directive}}"></div>
<div id="content" {{tab.directive}}></div>
```

Comment: So the only difference between fruitApple and fruitBanana is the template?

Comment: @jme11 No, this is just a trimmed down example, the directives are actually different

Answer (score 1):

In your template, use the directive variable to add directive as an attribute or class.  Make sure to allow attributes and classes in your directive declaration (restrict). Try

```
    <tabset type="pills" class="tabs-left" ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
        <tab heading="{{tab.title}}" class="hand_pointer" active="tab.active">
            <br/>
            <div class="content" {{tab.directive}} ></div>
        </tab>
    </tabset>
```

Or

```
<tabset type="pills" class="tabs-left" ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
            <tab heading="{{tab.title}}" class="hand_pointer" active="tab.active">
                <br/>
                <div class="content {{tab.directive}}"></div>
            </tab>
        </tabset>
```

Comment: My directive is restricted to 'AEC'. I don't understand what you mean, could you post a code example of the directive being used?

Comment: Also, I think you might need to move the ng-repeat attribute to the tabset tag.

Comment: I updated the example to reflect that change as well.

Comment: If I try either example then nothing happens (The template defined in the directive is not displayed). If I remove the {{tab.directive}} part and replace it with data-fruit-apple, the template is displayed for each tab. I don't think moving the ng-repeat is correct as that would create many tabsets (rather than many tabs) which wouldn't display correctly.

Comment: ng-repeat repeats the contents of the container, so if it is on the tabset, it will not repeat the tabset itself, rather it will repeat everything inside the tabset.

Comment: I don't think that's true, at least in the angular version that I am using. I have added a plunkr to my question that fully shows what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure if this will solve your problem, since you stated that you're trying to do "more" than what's represented in the question code and Plunker, but you really don't elaborate on what that "more" is.

It's possible that you don't really need more than one directive, or that a single directive with multiple some individual child directives using require, might do the trick. But, for what it's worth, here's how I'd do this:

## [Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Uufw5ueje6C9eqQTjmre?p=preview)

```
app.directive('fruit', function ($http, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        scope: {
          type: '@fruit'
        },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        var template = scope.type+"Template.html";

        function loadTemplate(template) {
          $http.get(template)
            .success(function(templateContent) {
              element.replaceWith($compile(templateContent)(scope));                
            });    
        }
        
        loadTemplate(template);
      }
    };
});
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.tabs = [
  { title:"Apple", type: 'apple' },
  { title:"Banana", type: 'banana' },
  { title:"Cherry", type: 'cherry' }
];
```

And your repeat would be:

```
<tabset type="pills">
  <tab heading="{{tab.title}}" class="hand_pointer" active="tab.active" ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
    <br />
    <div fruit="{{tab.type}}"></div>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```